# ZepplinOS: Where to set owner of the contract?

Tags: solidity, upgrading, openzeppelin-sdk, contract-upgrading

ZepplinOS contracts do not use constructors in it's zos implementation, and instead uses an `initialization` function that it imports from `zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol` package.

In order for the contract to have upgradeable state, the state variables need to be declared within the `initialization` function like so:

```
  bytes32[] public data;

  function initialize(bytes32[] _data) initializer public {
    data = _data;
  }
```

If I want to set the owner of the contract, would I simply set an `owner` variable in the `initialize` function? Not sure what the best practice is here.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol";

contract Verifications is Initializable { 

  mapping (bytes32 => bytes32) public data;
  address public owner;

  function initialize(bytes32[] _data) initializer public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    data = _data;
  }
}
```

Thoughts? Is this ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'd better to explicit the owner via input param like below, instead of using **msg.sender** since msg.sender might be not what we intend to set because zos use contract proxy to make it upgradable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "zos-lib/contracts/Initializable.sol";

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions".
 */
contract Ownable is Initializable {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
     * account.
     */
    function initialize(address sender) public initializer {
        _owner = sender;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), _owner);
    }

    /**
     * @return the address of the owner.
     */
    function owner() public view returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(isOwner());
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @return true if `msg.sender` is the owner of the contract.
     */
    function isOwner() public view returns (bool) {
        return msg.sender == _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Allows the current owner to relinquish control of the contract.
     * @notice Renouncing to ownership will leave the contract without an owner.
     * It will not be possible to call the functions with the `onlyOwner`
     * modifier anymore.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
     * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers control of the contract to a newOwner.
     * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal {
        require(newOwner != address(0));
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }

    uint256[50] private ______gap;
}
```